# ggplot2 - geom_line generating line equal to a ladder

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I verified that when using geom_line the resulting graph is not formed by solid lines, the lines look like a ladder.

Would anyone know how to get solid lines?

Here is the code used.

data base
0;0
0.000700;1.050
0.001750;1.100
0.003800;1.150
0.029110;1.200
0.130900;1.240
0.341428;1.303

```
`library(tidyverse)
library(reprex)

SAT <- read.delim("Curva_Tipica.txt", header = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
SAT <- str_split(SAT[[1]],";") 
length_SAT <- length(SAT) + 1
curva_VxI <- tibble(
  .rows = length_SAT,
  I = 0,
  V = 0,
)

for (linha in 2:length_SAT) {
  curva_VxI$I[linha] <- as.double(SAT[[linha-1]][1])
  curva_VxI$V[linha] <- as.double(SAT[[linha-1]][2])
}

Xac <- (curva_VxI$V[length_SAT] - curva_VxI$V[length_SAT-1])/(curva_VxI$I[length_SAT] - curva_VxI$I[length_SAT-1])
Vj <- curva_VxI$V[length_SAT] - Xac*curva_VxI$I[length_SAT]

Xac_grafico <- tibble(
  x = c(0, 1),
  y = c(0, Xac)
)

Vj_grafico <- tibble(
  x = c(0),
  y = c(Vj)
)

theme_set(theme_bw())

ggplot() +
  geom_point(
    data = curva_VxI,
    aes(x = I, y = V),
    color = "orange",
    size = 2
  ) +
  geom_line(
    data = curva_VxI,
    aes(x = I, y = V),
    color = "orange",
    linewidth = 1
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = Xac_grafico,
    aes(x = x, y = y),
    color = "blue",
  ) +
  geom_line(
    data = Xac_grafico,
    aes(x = x, y = y),
    color = "blue",
    linewidth = 1,
    linetype = "solid",
  ) +
  labs(
    y = "V (pu)",
    x = "I (pu)"
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(
    xlim = c(0, 1),
    ylim = c(0, 1.5),
    expand = FALSE,
    clip = "off"
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1, "Xac (pu)")) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10), size = 12, face = "bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 10), size = 12, face = "bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
    legend.position = "top",
    # plot.background = element_rect(fill = "gray60"),
    plot.margin = margin(t = 1, r = 1, b = 0.5, l = 0.5, unit = "cm"),
    
  )`
```

[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgCF8.png)

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA6NK.png)
[result obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68FTQ.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: OP, this is likely more related to how you are saving your plots and viewing them, rather than code.  Export your plot via `ggsave()` for more consistent results and to have more control on the graphics device used (png, jpeg, gif, etc).  Typically I end up saving plots in png format via something like `ggsave("filename.png", plot=..., width=..., height=..., dpi=...)`.